# I cannot edit files on a server which I access via fish or smb

Tags: networking, server, files, editing, fish-protocol

I can connect and open files on a server, to which I connect by using fish, but I cannot edit the files.
When I edit a file and want to save it I get the following message:

```
The file fish://root@[domain]/[path]/[filenname] has been modified.
Do you want to upload the changes?
```

In this Dialog I get two options: `Do Not Upload` and `Upload`

When I press `Upload`, i get an error message:

```
A file named fish://root@[domain]/[path]/[filenname] already exists.
```

I already tried connecting to the server via smb and I have the same problem there as well, I also tried to edit a file on another server and there I also have the same problem.

I didn't have that problem before I switched to ubuntu.

Comment: It feels lik.e a problem with mount parameters for the remote server, that you don't have write permissions. Talk to your network admin, or if that's you, then you might want to ask at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) for a more specifically sysadmin audience.